# Object reference is required for non-static field, method or property

Tags: c#, non-static, object-reference

working on a login method, using Mdi, and MVC. The Class structure is very elaborate, so constant references between classes is required. However, when I try to change the Main Menu view, I get the "object reference is required for non-static field, method or property".

I am still only an amateur, started 2 months ago and self-taught, so I am still fuzzy on what the error is actually referring to and what it means.

Here is the Menu View Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using DCIM_With_Test.User;

namespace DCIM_With_Test.Menu
{
     public partial class Menu_View : Form
     {
         public static int btnUser;

        public Menu_View()
        {
            InitializeComponent();  //runs the Main Menu form
             User_Controller CreateLoginView = new User_Controller(); //opens the Show_Login method in the User_Controller
            CreateLoginView.Show_Login(this); //sets the Mdi Parent container
        }

        public void SetMenuView()
        {
            switch (Db_Facade.ACCESS)
            {
                case 1:
                     plantAreaCodeToolStripMenuItem.Visible = true;
                     cableIDToolStripMenuItem.Visible = true;
                     logOutToolStripMenuItem.Visible = true;
                     createNewUserToolStripMenuItem.Visible = true;
                     editUserToolStripMenuItem.Visible = true;
                     break;
                 default:
                    plantAreaCodeToolStripMenuItem.Visible = false;
                    cableIDToolStripMenuItem.Visible = false;
                    logOutToolStripMenuItem.Visible = false;
                    createNewUserToolStripMenuItem.Visible = false;
                    editUserToolStripMenuItem.Visible = false;
                    break;
            }
        }
```

The User Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using DCIM_With_Test.Menu;

namespace DCIM_With_Test.User
{
    class User_Controller
    {
        public void Show_Login(Menu_View Main_Menu)
        {
            User_Login_View LoginView = new User_Login_View(); // Creates an object of the User_Login_View.
            LoginView.MdiParent = Main_Menu; // Set the Parent Form of the Child window.
            LoginView.Show(); // Display the new form.
        }

        public void Show_User(Menu_View Main_Menu)
        {
            User_Edit_View EditUserView = new User_Edit_View(); // Creates an objet of the User_View.
            EditUserView.MdiParent = Main_Menu; // Set the Parent Form of the Child window.
            EditUserView.Show(); // Display the new form.
        }

        public static void Compare_Login(User_Login_View Login_View)
        {
            User_Model getACCESS = new User_Model();
            getACCESS.uName = Login_View.txtUsername.Text;
            getACCESS.uPwd = Login_View.txtPassword.Text;

            Db_Facade.ACCESS = 1;

            if (Db_Facade.ACCESS > 0)
            {
                Login_View.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                Login_View.lblError.Visible = true;
            }

            Menu_View.SetMenuView(); //here is where the error occurs
        }
    }
}
```

The Db_Facade Class is currently just a collection of Variables, hence why ACCESS is set to 1 in the User_Controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem occurs because you don't have a reference to the `Menu_View` **object** inside your function, so it tries to reference the `Menu_View` **class**, which doesn't have any static members assigned.  It looks like what you want to do is call `Login_View.MdiParent.SetMenuView()`

**EDIT**

You probably need to cast your call, as you are saving `Main_Menu` into `LoginView.MdiParent` which stores it as it's base class `Form`.  Try:  `(Main_Menu)Login_View.MdiParent.SetMenuView()`

If casting the object isn't possible, then what you can do is create a Property to access the object directly.

In your `User_Login_View`, create a new property `public Menu_View Menu {get;set;}`.  Then, in your `Show_Login` function, add a line to set the `Menu` object `LoginView Menu = Main_Menu;`.  Now, you can reference `LoginView.Menu.SetMenuView();` without needing a cast.

Comment: well that sorted that issue, but now I've got another one: 'System.Windows.Forms.Form' does not contain a definition for 'SetMenuView' and no extension method 'SetMenuView' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Form' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Actually I had a thought. Could I put the "SetMenuView" call in a different method that does contain a reference to the main menu, and access it that way? Or would the reference to Menu_View still get in the way?

Comment: The main issue is with the way that you are storing the variable for future use.  When you create a variable you set the type that you expect stored in it. `MdiParent` is defined as a `Form` type, for example. You can store an object in that variable if it defines that signature somewhere in it's inheritance tree.  When you retrieve it, the Type it was stored under tells what is **directly** accessible for that object.  You would need to cast the object to access properties or methods further down the chain.  Or, you can create a property to specifically store the object as a `Main_Menu` Type.

Comment: My understanding of the accessors is still very basic, but I do follow how and why it works :)